# Investing.com scrape historical data with Powershell

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, invoke-webrequest

I was inspired by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53962832/14022403) and the function [get_stock_historical_data](https://github.com/alvarobartt/investpy/blob/master/investpy/stocks.py) in python module investpy to write in **Powershell** a function that retrieves all the daily prices of a stock between two dates :

```
$uri = 'https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax'

$params = @{
    'curr_id'= '951481'
    'smlID'= '2081817'
    'header'= 'STOXX 50 Volatility VSTOXX EUR Historical Data'
    'st_date'= '04/13/2021'
    'end_date'= '04/13/2002'
    'interval_sec'= 'Daily'
    'sort_col'= 'date'
    'sort_ord'= 'DESC'
    'action'= 'historical_data'
}

$headers = @{
    'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0'
    'X-Requested-With'= 'XMLHttpRequest'
    'Accept'= 'text/html'
    'Accept-Encoding'= 'gzip, deflate'}

$res = Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Headers $headers  -Uri $uri -Body $params -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded
$res.Content > .\test.txt
```

My issue is that the response contains

`<td colspan="7" class="arial_11 blueFont center">No results found</td>`

But it should return all the prices of the stock over a year

For information, when I send it directly from investing and inspect the page I get :

[image: General]

[image: Form]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: From `'st_date'= '04/13/2021'` to `'end_date'= '04/13/2002'` doesn't make much sense. I'm guessing it'll work much better if you change `end_date` to any date after what you specified in `st_date`.

Comment: It was just that ! I wanted to write 2022. I was looking for much more complicated explanations, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this particular example is the start date (`'st_date'='04/13/2021'`) being a date after the end date (`'end_date'='04/13/2002'`). The request is hence basically for data from after 2021 but before 2002, which doesn't quite make sense.

Changing the latter to any date *after* 04/13/2021 in this scenario should solve the problem.